# Eligible for German Blue Card. University is H+ on Anabin. However B.A.LL.B is not

Tags: germany, blue-card

B.A.LL.B is quite a popular degree in India, being issued since the 80s. Although my university is H+ the degree it issued is not.

Do I need to write to ZAB?

Any suggestions on a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in a similar situation, my university is recognized as `H+` in Anabin, however my degree program is not.

I proactively sent a certified copy of my degree to the KMK for [recognition](https://anabin.kmk.org/no_cache/filter/anerkennungs-und-beratungsstellen-in-deutschland.html). The process cost me 300€ and took just over 3 months.

They will make a determination as to whether your degree is equivalent to a German degree.

Should the KMK recognize your degree as equivalent to a German degree, you would provide the Ausländeramt with the recognition from the KMK with your application for a Blue Card.

I applied for and received a Blue Card in NRW in 2016 by providing the Ausländeramt with the KMK evaluation of my degree.