# Is my university degree recognised if my university is Listed as H+ on anabin database but my degree is not listed?

Tags: visa

My university is recognised but my major is not listed on the database. I asked anabin and they said that in order to add it to their database, the university must email them. And I emailed the university asking them to do that.

Now if by any chance they couldn't do it, then what should I do? Certificate of compatibility?

Comment: Here is a [related question and answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15109/eligible-for-german-blue-card-university-is-h-on-anabin-however-b-a-ll-b-is-n/15698#15698).